# android how to keep session open without using cookies after connecting to web with more than one url?

Tags: android, session, httpurlconnection

i am writing an android application where it is required to log in to a web server, and later in the application when the user request to view portfolio information the server will check if the user session is still open other wise the user will be considered unknown and will be redirected to the log in page.

i managed to log in using header fields via HttpURLConnection, and read response successfully; but when trying to re-connect to the server to read portfolio the user is always considered unknown; after a long trials and search on the net i found out that the login connection session is closed automatically after the response is retrieved, i tried some code that assumes the server keep track of logged in users via cookies but it failed because (later i found out) that the server does not use cookies to track logged in users!
i need help in solving this issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying various methods, i found that the only way to do it is by defining a global HttpClient and keep it open, then use it with different local HttpPost to change the page i need to view while keeping the same connected session open!